# transforming an application at run time without bringing down the application

Tags: dynamic, runtime, metaprogramming

My problem statement is 
"transforming an application with changes during runtime wothout bringing down the application instance ( without - killing it or stopping it  )".

which framework or programming language has this feature.
Thanks for your support in-advance.

Comment: What kind of application are you thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

It is operating system dependent and language specific.

A good candidate is [Common Lisp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp) notably [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/) on Linux. Or [kernel](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~jshutt/kernel.html) (a [Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/) dialect).

You could also use [dynamic loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading). Even C or C++ with [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) on Linux. (for example, [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) generates C++ code, compiles it to some [shared object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_object), and  `dlopen`-s it...., all at runtime).  Or Ocaml's [dynlink](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Dynlink.html), etc... And of course Java and other JVM based implementations (Scala, Clojure...) with [class loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader). Also [erlang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_%28programming_language%29) ...

You could use program generator libraries, like e.g. [libjit](http://www.gnu.org/software/libjit/) or [llvm](http://llvm.org/).

If the application is long living, you also need to care about [garbage collecting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) old dead code.

What would be very difficult is to alter the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) at runtime (e.g. change some call stack frame to another one). Read about [continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [call/cc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call-with-current-continuation).

Read also about [homoiconicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity), [application checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing), [persistence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_%28computer_science%29), [multistage programming](http://loome.cs.uiuc.edu/CS498F09/readings/mint-pldi.pdf), [just-in-time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation), [eval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval), [generative metaprogramming](http://okmij.org/ftp/meta-programming/), [type introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) and [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29).

BTW, Pitrat's book [artificial beings: the conscience of a conscious machine](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/9780470611791) illustrates why it is useful to change its own code. See also [his blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/). And *runtime modularity* is still a research subject. See e.g. [this](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/150347/files/gpce63-rompf.pdf), ... and Queinnec's [Lisp In Small Pieces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_In_Small_Pieces).

<sup>PS: you can still make your PhD on the subject. If you do, I'll be delighted to read you!</sup>